# Solspace User - editing member categories in CP

Tags: solspace-user

Can an EE administrator with CP access be able to re-assign member categories from the EE member admin area?
I have a Solspace User reg form that allows the user to select from a list of categories, question is how can administrators edit those categories on a per member basis from within EE CP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this feature isn't available for the CP. I recommend submitting this as a Feature Request under the specific add-on category. It'll also give other users the option to vote up the feature request, and help us prioritize features to add in upcoming versions of this add-on.
http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions

Alternatively you could use the `{exp:user:edit}` form (http://www.solspace.com/docs/user/edit/) on a front-end template only accessible by admins and let them manage categories for users from there.

Lastly, you could work in the exp_user_category_posts table, but we can't recommend you doing that unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks. I have already started coding a plugin for handling this.